# Special characters giving an error when adding data fields for pivot table?

Tags: excel, vba

A pivot table that I created adds a data field with a name that contains a dash in it. The error I get is:

Run-time error '1004'. Application-defined or object-defined error.

The line of code is:

```
PvtTable.AddDataField PvtTable.PivotFields("AH-values"), "AH-values", xlSum
```

If I were to remove the "-" in the line of code above and in the header of the source data, the code runs as supposed to. How do I keep the "-" in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dash is not the problem.

Using

```
PvtTable.AddDataField PvtTable.PivotFields("AH-values"), "AH-values", xlSum
```

you tries creating a new field named "AH-values" which is a sum filed for values of the already existing field named "AH-values". This is not possible because each field must have it's own unambiguously name.

Thats why

```
PvtTable.AddDataField PvtTable.PivotFields("AHvalues"), "AH-values", xlSum
```

will work because now the new field named "AH-values" is a sum filed for values of the already existing field named "AHvalues". So field names are not equal.

But

```
PvtTable.AddDataField PvtTable.PivotFields("AH-values"), "Sum of AH-values", xlSum
```

will also work.

Comment: I see. Didn't realize that, as I saw a prepared pivot table which uses the same field name for both values. This was prepared manually though and not by a macro. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @MelBee: "uses the same field name for both": No definitely not. But "AH-values" and "AH-values " are not the same. Note the space behind the second. But this is not good practice at all.

Comment: Right. That could be the case.